# The @mention system does not produce the correct output

Tags: php

The following function is not getting a correct results:

```
function getMentions($content) {
    global $db;
    $mention_regex = "/@+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/"; //mention regrex to get all @texts
    $regexIt = preg_match_all($mention_regex, $content, $matches);
    if ($regexIt) { 
         foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
             if ($key === 0) continue;
                 $mentioned[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $match[0]);
                 $match_user = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM dot_users WHERE user_name  IN ('" . implode("','", $matches[1]) . "')") or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
                 $userDeti = mysqli_fetch_array($match_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                 echo $userDeti['user_id'];
                 echo $userDeti['user_name'];
                 $match_search = '@' . $match . '';  
                 $match_replace = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $userDeti['user_name'] . '">@' . $userDeti['user_name'] . '</a>'; 
                 if (isset($userDeti['user_name'])) {
                        $content = str_replace($match_search, $match_replace, $content);
                   }
            }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

For example, I want to print the user_name and user_id on the screen, but it does not print.

```
echo $userDeti['user_id']; // echo is empty
echo $userDeti['user_name'];  //echo is empty output
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or incomplete?

Comment: on which line you print $userDeti['user_name']

Comment: We're gonna need an actual error message and a clear indication of the line number to help you.

Comment: How about a simpler pattern `~@\K[\w-]+~` this way you can just process the fullstring matches `[0]`.

Comment: @mickmackusa the output warning : `Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in `

Comment: @rpm192 I didn't get any error message. If i get error message then i will put it here.

Comment: var_export($matches);

Comment: @mickmackusa Now the output is: `array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '@mustafa', 1 => '@admin', 2 => '@cemal', 3 => '@huseyin', 4 => '@sezgin', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'mustafa', 1 => 'admin', 2 => 'cemal', 3 => 'huseyin', 4 => 'sezgin', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '@mustafa', 1 => '@admin', 2 => '@cemal', 3 => '@huseyin', 4 => '@sezgin', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'mustafa', 1 => 'admin', 2 => 'cemal', 3 => 'huseyin', 4 => 'sezgin', ), )array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '@mustafa', 1 => '@admin', 2 => '@cemal', 3 => '@huseyin', 4 => '@sezgin', ), 1 => array (..... )`

Comment: Not if you use my pattern it isn't. And you don't need to escape because the data is already clean/safe.  Why are you ignoring the first match? Why is every iteration searching for all users?

Comment: @mickmackusa I isee the output after your `var_export($matches);`

Comment: You should be querying just one time, then creating an associative lookup array from the result set, then use `strtr()` to update `$content`. This is the best support I can offer from my phone.

Comment: @mickmackusa If i write `echo $userDet['user_name'];` then output is 5 time same name.  Like `mickmackusamickmackusamickmackusamickmackusamickmackusa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My untested suggestion...

```
function getMentions($content) {
    global $db;  // I would rather this be passed as a function argument
    if (preg_match_all("/\B@\K[\w-]+/", $content, $matches)) { 
        if (!$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM dot_users WHERE user_name  IN ('" . implode("','", $matches[0]) . "')")) {
            // error
        } else {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $content = preg_replace("~\B@{$row["user_name"]}\b~", "<a href=\"{$row["user_id"]}\">@{$row["user_name"]}</a>", $content);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

There may be typos, but the general idea is there.  Capture mentions and try to avoid emails, look up the ids, replace all mentions.

Comment: @Azzo does this actually run?

Comment: Can i ask you something related your answer please ?

Comment: Is there anyway to fined the username in the gapless text like this: `@mickmackusaisabesthelpfuluseronstackoverflow`. You see in this text normaly `@mickmackusa is a best helpful user on stackoverflow`. But there is not have a space. We can fined the username like this texts ?

Comment: You can remove the word boundaries `\b` and `\B` to relax the patterns, but then you risk "overmatching". Imagine `@mick` and `@mickmack`. Depending in the time of replacement, you will generate nested `<a>` tags.